# cppyy execution errorr libcppyy_backend non existent

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

Im new to using C++ and looked into cppyy, seems like a nice package and the examples seem easy enough but there is alot of things to install, ive already installed:
cppyy
cppyy-backend
MS Studio C++ package
but keep getting this error

```
RuntimeError: could not load cppyy_backend library, details:
  [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
  Could not find module 'libcppyy_backend.cp310-win_amd64.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  Could not find module 'C:\Users\danya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cppyy_backend\lib\libcppyy_backend.cp310-win_amd64.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  Could not find module 'libcppyy_backend.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

this is my code

```
import cppyy
cppyy.cppdef(r"""\
void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}""")
cppyy.gbl.hello()
```

im on windows btw

tried reinstalling packages but dint work

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are but it's much easier to just learn C++ without adding the complexity of embedding it in python scripts. By mixing C++ into python scripts you'll have to get familiar with _two_ new things.

Comment: im familliar with python and ahve recently taken on C++ , i just wanted to know how to fix the library errors, my requirements r to create a python file with C++ in string format

Comment: @DanyalNoorani "my requirements r to create a python file with C++ in string format" - C++ is not a scripting language. It's a compiled language. You cannot just include C++ code in string form in a Python script and run it. You need to compile the C++ code into a binary (probably a shared library) and then you can invoke functions in that library from Python (given the proper wrappers/bindings). But, that's a non-trivial task for a beginner.

Comment: I think, listen to @JesperJuhl a bit. I would say the same things, just not in so many words. :)

Comment: What is the traceback prior to the above error? Usually this problem occurs as a cascade from not being able to find the system headers from the MSVC installation.

Comment: As for "You cannot just include C++ code in string form in a Python script and run it. " from @JesperJuhl ... well, that's what cppyy allows you to do. :)